# Is there a way I can cause an ActionListener to cancel?

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener

I have an action listener that I want to cancel the current iteration of if a variable value is `null`.

```
public class ValidateListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myCalendarKey mCal = Project5.verifyDate(month+"/"+day+"/"+year); //month day and year are defined, just not in this code display.

        if (mCal == null) e.cancel(); //I need something to cancel the current ActionEvent if this returns true.

        /* A lot more code down here that only works if mCal is defined */
   }
}
```

I guess I could use a if-else statement and make it do everything if  `mCal != null`, and do nothing if `mCal == null`, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: *"is there a better way to do this?"*  There is nothing wrong with that way.  Alternately, disable the control or `Action` when the value is `null` - then the event will not be fired in the first place!

Comment: @Andrew The approach above doesn't cancel the action (which seems to be the requirement - although I might be wrong).  It just stops the processing of this particular event listener.

Comment: "I am not especially interested in speculation from people who are not the OP" - you must be a pleasure to work with.

Comment: There's no Swing guarantee that your ActionListener will be the first ActionListener called.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
e.consume()
```

This will consume the event:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html#consume()

Comment: But it is protected -.-

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    myCalendarKey mCal = Project5.verifyDate(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
    if(mCal != null) {
        /* A lot more code down here that only works if mCal is defined */


    }
 }
```

Comment: This stops the logic of the action listener but won't cancel the event (which I think is the requirement).

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't say it's better, but you could also do this.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   myCalendarKey mCal = Project5.verifyDate(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
   if(mCal != null) return;
   ...
}
```